# Shortest path from starting cell to all cells in the grid

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, shortest-path, square-grid

I found an algorithm for finding the shortest path on grid between selected cell, to all cells on the grid, with $O(KN)$ where $K$ is the number of neighbor cells and $N$ is the number of cells.

How ever if that's true than it's better than [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), [Floyd–Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) and many others. So I probably mistaking some thing. Can you point me what.

Here is a pseudo code for my algorithm, the idea is to calculate simultaneously to all the directions.

The algorithm starts with the call to filter method

```
class MapFilter
{
    declare cellsMap, array of numbers with two dimensions, that represent a grid
    declare stack, a stack of MapFilter
    declare count of type number
    read input to map, array of Cells with two dimensions, that represent a grid
    read input to x ,y those are coordinates of starting node

    function filter(){
        initialize cellsMap with empty grid, all values are 0
        set count = 1
        set cellsMap[x][y] = 1;
        execute();
        while(stack is not empty){
            read length of the stack to length
            iterate over i from 0 to length{
                remove first element from stack and store it in mapFilter, instance of MapFilter
                mapFilter.execute()
            }
        }
    }

    function execute()
    {
        populate(x + 1, y);
        populate(x - 1, y);
        populate(x, y + 1);
        populate(x, y - 1);
    }

    function populate(x, y)
    {
        // Testing if the x,y cell is blocked by some way
        if( not isInMapRange(x,y) or
            cellsMap[x][y] not empty or{
            return;
        }

        set cellsMap[x][y] to count;
        addTask(x,y);
    }

    function isInMapRange(x,y){
        return x < cellsMap.length && 
            x >= 0 &&
            y < cellsMap[0].length && 
            y >= 0;
    }

    function addTask(x, y)
    {
        initialize mapFilter;

        set mapFilter.map = this.map
        set mapFilter.cellsMap = this.cellsMap
        set mapFilter.count = this.count + 1
        set mapFilter.x = x
        set mapFilter.y = y
        add mapFilter to stack 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unweighted, undirected graph with $N$ vertices, and where each vertex has degree $K$.  Then the problem of computing shortest paths *can* be solved in $O(KN)$ time using simple breadth-first search.

Why is this faster than Floyd-Warshall etc.?  Because Floyd-Warshall has to handle *weighted* graphs.  In your case you have an *unweighted* graph: every edge has weight 1 (the length of a path is just the number of edges in it).  There are faster algorithms for computing shortest paths in unweighted graphs than in weighted graphs; unsurprisingly, the problem is harder if you have a weighted graph.  If you have an unweighted graph, you don't need the fancier algorithms, like Floyd-Warshall; breadth-first search is enough.